# SQL function to read null fields and update with a string value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an insert that is recording data from a webform and inserting it into my table. I'd like to run an update immediately after my insert that reads the previous insert and finds all the `null` fields and updates that record's `null` fields with a string of `--`

The data-type for all my fields is varchar

I have 20+ forms each with 100+ fields so i'm looking for a function that would be smart enough to read/update the fields that have `null` values without specifically enumerating/writing out each field for the update statement. This would just take way too long.

Does anyone know of a way to read simply which fields have `null` values and update any fields that are `null` to a string, in my case `--`

Comment: Instead of update after insert you may try changing table structure. Set default value of the columns to `--`. If while insert no value is provided, `--` will be inserted automatically.

Comment: if you dont want nulls,why cant you change that during inserts

Comment: @वरुण Is this something that can be setup through SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @TheGameiswar it would be possible to change on the inserts, but it would take a very long time for all of the forms, i'm trying to find a quick way to update everything rather than modify what's already working.

Comment: @वरुण I found it! I think this will solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexP You can do this with SQL Management Studio. User `ALTER TABLE` command. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp.

Comment: @AlexP Welcome. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of update after insert you may try changing table structure.

Set default value of the columns to --. If while insert no value is provided, -- will be inserted automatically.

Answer (score 2):

IF you can't alter your existing code,I would go with insert trigger...so after every insert,you can check and see the null values and update them like below

```
create trigger triggername
on table
after insert
as
begin

    update t
    set t.col1=isnull(i.col1,'--'),
        t.col2=isnull(i.col2,'--')
     rest of cols
    from table t
         join
         inserted i
    on i.matchingcol=t.mtachingcol
    end
```

The issue with above approach is,you will have to check all inserted rows..I would go with this approach only,since filtering many cols with many `or` clauses is not good for performance

If is to just for display purposes,i would go with view

Comment: i've just discovered that you can attribute a default value when column is null so that seems to be the fastest way but It's good to know I can use a trigger to do the same thing. The only down-fall with this is i would have to enumerate all my columns in the above code 100+ x 20+ foms which was my reason for trying to find the fastest way. Thank you